# Как отобразить гифку на страничке(Spring boot)

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Есть вот такой контроллер, запрос отправляется при помощи FeignClient(здесь это GifClient)

```
  @RestController
  @Controller
public class MainController {

 @Autowired
private GifClient gifClient;

  @GetMapping()
public String asdf(Model model) {

    String rich = "rich";
    String broke = "broke";

    Gif richie = gifClient.getMyGif(rich);
    String url = richie.getData().getImages().getOriginal().getUrl();
    System.out.println(url);
    Gif brokee = gifClient.getMyGif(broke);

    model.addAttribute("rich", richie);

    return "someHtml";
}
```

как я могу из этого контроллера вывести гифку на экран, проблемы с JS и HTML
не пойму как с тимлифом создать переменнуюд которая бы хранила json или url  с файлом, которую можно было бы передать в скрипт и там уже отобразить

```
    <body>
 <img th:src="rich">
 <script>
    
 </script>
 </body>
```

в src лежить String url как его отобразить на страничке что бы это не были просто вывод самой строки с ссылкой а автоматическое представление самой гифки при гет запросе с сайта

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за внимание, в итоге решение здесь img th:src="${rich}" Переменную rich нужно было обернуть долларом и скобками, а так же убираем аннотацию @RestController